# TypeScript can't infer generic type when T is conditional

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a React component where its properties change based on the type of a generic property.

```ts
interface PropsBase<T> {
  value: T;
  children: (value: T) => ReactElement;
}

type ArrayType<T extends any[]> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

interface ArrayProps<T extends any[]> extends Omit<PropsBase<T>, 'children'> {
  children: (value: ArrayType<T>, index: number, array: T) => ReactElement;
}

type Props<T> = T extends any[] ? ArrayProps<T> : PropsBase<T>;

const MyComp = <T extends any>({ value, children }: Props<T>) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return <>{value.map(children)}</>;
  }
  
  return <div>{children(value)}</div>;
};
```

If `value` is an array, then the child it expects is a function that's applied to each element in the array.  Otherwise it expects a function that just takes in the value.

For reasons I have yet to determine, when `Props` is conditional as it is above, it cannot determine the type of `T`.

```ts
const val = { a: 10 };
const rendered = 
  <MyComp value={val}>
    {value => <span>{value.a}</span>}
  </MyComp>;

// error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

This is the case even if both results of the ternary operator are identical.

```ts
type Props<T> = T extends any[] ? PropsBase<T> : PropsBase<T>;
// same error
```

Any other props, including ones only listed in `ArrayProps` are correctly inferred.

```ts
interface ArrayProps<T extends any[]> extends Omit<PropsBase<T>, 'children'> {
  children: (value: ArrayType<T>, index: number, array: T) => ReactElement;
  arrayOpt: boolean;
}

const array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const renderedArray =
  <MyComp value={array} arrayOpt>
    {value => <span>{value}</span>}
  </MyComp>;
```

If I had to guess, this is a bug in tsc.  Meanwhile, is there any way around this?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-M9rLo4OwYEYoNGVBocGGMyAUGA3JGXD5qCohYKXtEBCXy5Xq45gHpa63KHmvO3O8PR1EJnwnS74J46XgUOYAIwABhjViXrrLRRESEcdJeKg93vA+nzSH8dcM1A0L10j68AS0KlkYDKtfrKAdkKP5-r2uidlePrdn2B7wFi6R0hUcCbtgABM2AAMxwFU+7OoeLjAuwji-AEF6QTeYYPvBcS0NROIwC+JZvmGn5wN+v4UP+d5ASBnFgWxQrkWAgpAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's messy, but I found a workaround.

```ts
interface MyComp<T> extends FunctionComponent<Props<T>> {};
function MyComp<T extends any[]>(props: ArrayProps<T>): ReactElement;
function MyComp<T>(props: PropsBase<T>): ReactElement;
function MyComp<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  const {
    value,
    children,
    arrayOpt,
  } = props as PropsBase<T> & { arrayOpt: boolean };

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return <>{value.map(children)}</>;
  } else {
    return <div>{(children as PropsBase<T>['children'])(value)}</div>;
  }
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiArgHYbATEDCE4FSxWiqGAogDZIj3wC+cAZlBpwA5FGYwRAbgCwAKHnAGSKP3RI4ABSFgAzgCEUupAB4AKgD5c8uHABuKNoSQAuOGdlzbaABbA2ACbixG4AFA5Oru4AlHAAvFbI6DDsnNyePPLyMACeYBoAglBQKDlmeaZmcEgAHjD0AbpwKMQ5ANoAulZx7tV1DU1FJTkmSvwqcACqVgD8U3BuxEh2Kp6KyqrqcEOl2hB65n31xI3NrZ1WtcenAPIgwDAme3qGxuYW2CK+-kH0IlY4Gxwb6BYJhCLONw7MoVd7YJQBWqLQggABGKmwKGKpTcZliCSYyVSXAYnlsWOGNzAMDcqIgEA4LQyWTkuXyWh0une8V6VwGZ3aHTgc2hzy5lgWHP2BiMlQsazkSnqmzQGgAsjlqOBuXyTk0iKQYOQqDRIEsGE9Oe8ATxPPwSGQKHANVqwIddacWoKLKEwJyodicmL3tE3ElWBwSTA7Q6jU6Xab3r7-VKXrKQ2GJMT0vJ7Ybjc7NYnLMnpW5g5ZYoCvMCKLp4NXbLYIUhMEDvH5QfQ2zXyYGqVggXwen7pc0mmLXnK4AAyXDNfvU2n0xnEOC2lm2YD8OChaEAOmAumh4UczmiVfbcHEMEIUDXJgsOBb+5AKDAoRBv2I0R4JgA9PKQ7VGwxjWL215ILe95wCYATAHYT6fp237jqmMpvJYbRfChwQiB00SnpEv4AfBiFkuu8gbgochoHW8ARDyeAoG4ACMAAM66eHRxD1pBJwqEgAQ8kCJgJuA9hnkgcTPo4PAWFesmRPEVgmLoYAtE+L4oH+-7qZpmQ1gB4lgEBNE8XxFKlDybRwKx2AAEzYAAzHAHTcfR-GIuIATQvEokmZJkQyVZOR8KFA4KRBSnOCpsH6cQWlSbpCUWIZtjGUW4DykAA)